# java.nio.BufferUnderflowException at converting [] bytes to long

Tags: java, android, arrays

I've got problem with my bytes array. I try to convert it to long , then to hex and show it as a toast. However I get java.nio.BufferUnderflowException. Here's my code :

```
 public void onReceivedData(byte[] arg0)
        {
            String tag = null;
            long tagValue = ByteBuffer.wrap(arg0).getLong();
            tag = Long.toHexString(tagValue).toUpperCase();

}
```

Problem is at line :

```
        long tagValue = ByteBuffer.wrap(arg0).getLong();
```

I looked for information about this exception but none of the answers was solution for my problem.

This is logcat:

```
Process: com.example.eltegps011.eltegps, PID: 17304
                                                                                java.nio.BufferUnderflowException
                                                                                    at java.nio.ByteArrayBuffer.getLong(ByteArrayBuffer.java:211)
                                                                                    at com.example.eltegps011.eltegps.fragments.StocktakingFragment$9.onReceivedData(StocktakingFragment.java:504)
                                                                                    at com.felhr.usbserial.UsbSerialDevice$WorkerThread.onReceivedData(UsbSerialDevice.java:261)
                                                                                    at com.felhr.usbserial.UsbSerialDevice$WorkerThread.run(UsbSerialDevice.java:235)
```

Comment: Check the size of arg0 and do what you need if the size is wrong. A multile of 8 seems to be the right choice in you case.

Comment: Is it possible to set arg0 dynamically ?

Comment: I don't know what you exactly whant to do. the byte array is just wapped in the byte buffer. So if you cange the ByteBuffer the byte array will also be affected by the changes. So yes. and arg0 is not const. therefore an other yes.

Comment: I should get one byte array with 9 bytes in it. Instead of this I get one array with one byte and one with 8 bytes. I think, this is the problem.

Comment: could you tell me how can I fix it ?

Comment: Check out my updated answer. use the function I added to convert your array into a long or make sure args has the correct size.

Comment: Do you need to pass an index to getLong? `long tagValue = ByteBuffer.wrap(arg0).getLong(0);`

Comment: Dobz, no I don't. I just need to get whole array (one byte from first, and eleven from second).

Comment: You should probably open up a new question because of the wrong byte size array  issue?

Comment: I will do as you suggest :)

Answer (score 0):

As you seem to have a variable number of bytes:

```
arg0 = Arrays.copy(arg0, 8);
```

So you have 8 bytes for a long: xx xx ... 00 00

---

Or maybe you just need a hex dump of the bytes array:

```
public String bytesToString(byte[] bytes) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(bytes.length * 3);
    for (int i = 0; i < bytes.length; ++i) {
        sb.append(String.format("%02X ", 0xFF & bytes[i]));
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: I still get two arrays :/ First one have one byte and second eight bytes.

Comment: Extended the answer, with a hex dump, added a space after ever 2 hex digits for clarity.

Comment: Joop thx, it works , but still : 07-08 10:22:57.181 15705-16302/com.example.eltegps011.eltegps E/StocktakingFragment: onReceivedData: DA 
07-08 10:22:57.181 15705-16302/com.example.eltegps011.eltegps E/StocktakingFragment: onReceivedData: AD 06 74 01 6F 6B 26 0B

Comment: it should be DA AD 06 74 01 6F 6B 26

Comment: That DA seems to have been gone missing / read already. Good luck debugging.

Answer (score -1):

Add a check before getting long value from ByteBuffer

```
ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(arg0);
            if(byteBuffer.remaining()>0){
                long tagValue= byteBuffer.getLong();
                tag = Long.toHexString(tagValue).toUpperCase();
            }
```